# What is the best way to show/hide a form row if a particular drop down option is selected?

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-4

I have a form dropdown list and my goal is to able a user to select "Other" and what I want to happen is to make a form row appear below so the user can type in the "Other" option text. Here is my code below, I'm not sure if Bootstrap naturally has a built in hide/show function. I am using latest version if that helps. Many thanks in advance!

```
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 offset-md-3 mx-auto">
    <label class="control-label custom_label col-xs-12">Cemetery</label>
    <select type="dropdown" name="cemetery" class="form-control" id="mySelect">
      <option value="select" selected="selected">Select Cemetery</option>
      <option value="AK">Akatarawa</option>
      <option value="TA">Taita</option>
      <option value="WA">Wainuiomata</option>
      <option value="WH">Whenua Tapu</option>
      <option value="MA">Makara</option>
      <option value="KA">Karori</option>
      <option value="ST">St Johns</option>
      <option value="AW">Awa Tapu</option>
      <option value="PA">Paraparaumu</option>
      <option value="other">Other</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

The form row below I want to appear when above "other" option is selected and of course disappear when another dropdown option is selected.

```
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 offset-md-3 mx-auto">
    <input type="text" id="other" class="form-control" name="cemetery" placeholder="Enter other Cemetery">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please show the specific piece of code that's not working?

Answer (score 0):

We can make use of bootstrap util class "d-block" and "d-none" to show/hide the containers.

```
   function handleSelect() {
       var selected = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
       var details = document.getElementById("other-details");
       if (selected === "other") {
         details.classList.remove("d-none");
         details.classList.add("d-block");
      } else {
         details.classList.remove("d-block");
         details.classList.add("d-none");
      }
    }
```

Working [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-haslett-y5414?file=/index.html:345-767)

Answer (score 0):

I have added both a JQuery option and a vanilla JS option. Both I also added an ID to the option tag with the value of "other". Simply added an `id="other"` attribute to that tag.

Using JQuery you can use `.show()` and `.hide()` to show/hide the input when the other option is selected.

```js
var other = $("#other");
var otherInput = $(".otherInput");
otherInput.hide();
$('#mySelect').on('change', function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  if(value === "other"){
    otherInput.show();
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 offset-md-3 mx-auto">
            <label class="control-label custom_label col-xs-12">Cemetery</label>
            <select type="dropdown" name="cemetery" class="form-control" id="mySelect">
                <option value="select" selected="selected">Select Cemetery</option>
                <option value=" AK">Akatarawa</option>
                <option value="TA">Taita</option>
                <option value="WA">Wainuiomata</option>
                <option value="WH">Whenua Tapu</option>
                <option value="MA">Makara</option>
                <option value="KA">Karori</option>
                <option value="ST">St Johns</option>
                <option value="AW">Awa Tapu</option>
                <option value="PA">Paraparaumu</option>
                <option id="other" value="other">Other</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row otherInput">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 offset-md-3 mx-auto">
            <input type="text" id="other" class="form-control" name="cemetery" placeholder="Enter other Cemetery">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Vanilla JS: 
First set your `other` input div to hidden using js `.style`. Then create a onload function and add an event listener for change. Run a conditional on the value and change the style if the conditional is true.

```js
otherInput.style.display = "none";
window.onload = function () {
  var selectBox = document.getElementById("mySelect");
  selectBox.addEventListener('change', changeFunc);
  function changeFunc() {
    if(this.value === "other"){
      otherInput.style.display = "block";
    }else{
       otherInput.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 offset-md-3 mx-auto">
            <label class="control-label custom_label col-xs-12">Cemetery</label>
            <select type="dropdown" name="cemetery" class="form-control" id="mySelect">
                <option value="select" selected="selected">Select Cemetery</option>
                <option value=" AK">Akatarawa</option>
                <option value="TA">Taita</option>
                <option value="WA">Wainuiomata</option>
                <option value="WH">Whenua Tapu</option>
                <option value="MA">Makara</option>
                <option value="KA">Karori</option>
                <option value="ST">St Johns</option>
                <option value="AW">Awa Tapu</option>
                <option value="PA">Paraparaumu</option>
                <option id="other" value="other">Other</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="otherInput" class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 offset-md-3 mx-auto">
            <input type="text" id="other" class="form-control" name="cemetery" placeholder="Enter other Cemetery">
        </div>
    </div>
```